# How to use flutter firebase functions for free

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am getting this error :

> Error: Your project `myproject` must be on the Blaze (pay-as-you-go) plan to complete this command. Required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com
> can't be enabled until the upgrade is complete. To upgrade, visit the following URL:

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fluttershare-d057e/usage/details

while using this command : `firebase deploy --only functions`
which means I have to purchase flutter functions to proceed. Now I want to know is there any alternative way to deploy function like onCreate() free or can we build these functions manually for firebase ? I am using flutter technology.

Comment: As you can see in the [official pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing?hl=es-419) there is no way you can use the Firebase cloud functions for free.

Comment: Note that the fact you need to be on a paid plan doesn't necessarily mean you'll have to pay for Cloud Functions usage. On the same pricing page that Brugui linked you can see that there's a significant free tier.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Brugui and @FrankvanPruffelen answers, you need the [Blaze](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) plan in order to use Cloud Functions, however, it doesn't necessarily mean you'll have to pay for Cloud Functions usage as there's a significant free tier.